# NumPy's Random-Mulitnomial: How to never get 0 in output?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to produce a list/array of values that sum up to a value, but seem to be at a loss for how to prevent a 0 from landing in this list:

```
size = 11
levels = 6
np.random.multinomial(size, np.ones(levels)/levels, size=1)[0]

Output: array([2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3])
```

Is this going to have to use a while loop to check for zeros since you can eventually get a nonzero outcome? This seems not very sophisticated. So, just wondering if there is a fancy way to do this. Or, do I need to be using a different function altogether instead of numpy.random.multinomial? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could offset everything by 1:

```py
size = 11
levels = 6
1 + np.random.multinomial(size - levels, np.ones(levels)/levels, size=1)[0]

Output: array([2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3])
```

That would guarantee at least one entry in each level, and randomly distribute the rest of the samples.